# How would you find if a string contains a substring exactly with non-alphanumeric in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, substring

I was trying to design something that sees if a string contains exactly another substring, and they contain non-alphanumeric

For example:

```
const subStr = '#320';
const str1 = '#320 people';
const str2 = '#3202 people';
const str3 = "1#3202 people';
```

str1 should match because it contains exactly #320
str2 should not match because it contains an extra 2 at the end
str3 should not match because it contains an extra 1 at the front

I can't seem to figure something out that works

Comment: You'd have to define what delimiters are allowed before and after what you're looking for.  Is it only space characters or begin/end of string that are allowed?  What about newline characters?  What about punctuation characters?  Your question does not specify enough detail about what is and isn't allowed for anyone to craft a complete answer that wasn't just a guess.

Comment: Would `a#320people` work?

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey, sorry for not clarifying. It needs to be an EXACT match of the inputted, like literally 100% identical.

Comment: @OFRBG No, see my previous comment it must be 100% matching.

Comment: @chemslatt123 - Please read my previous comment and supply an answer to ALL the questions posted there.  The one example you say you want to match `str1` is NOT a 100% string match.  It has a space delimiter and other things in the string.  What about `"#320\npeople"` or `"    #320."` or `"#320; people"`.

Comment: Please note is very hard to help you when you take 14 hours to respond to clarifying questions  That is probably why you have downvotes on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just base on your input, I write this very ugly solution but it works anyway:

```js
const subStr = '#320';
const str1 = '#320 people';
const str2 = '#3202 people';
const str3 = '1#3202 people';

const filter = (target, condition) => (` ${target} `.includes(` ${condition} `));

console.log(filter(str1, subStr)); // true
console.log(filter(str2, subStr)); // false
console.log(filter(str3, subStr)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you really want is `#320` with either whitespace, newline or begin or end of string before/after it, then you can accomplish that with a regex.

```js
const testStrings = [
    '#320 people',
    '   #320 people',
    '#3202 people',
    '1#3202 people',
    'Other stuff #320 people',
    'Other line\n#320 people',
    'people #320',
    'people #320\n'
];

const regex = /(^|\s)#320(\s|$)/m;

for (let str of testStrings) {
    const match = regex.test(str);
    const matchStr = match ? "matches  " : "no match "
    console.log(`${matchStr}: "${str}"`);
}
```